# Angular 5 sort by date

Tags: angular, sorting, date, angular5

I have a table of lessons and I would like to order them by date. Since Angular 5 doesn't have the orderBy pipe and all the solutions I have found so far can only be applied to numbers and strings I would be grateful if someone could help me with this. This is the body of my table

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let lesson of lessons">
    <th scope="row">{{lesson.date | date:'dd.MM.yyyy H:mm'}}</th>
    <td>{{lesson.address.locationName}}</td>
    <td>{{lesson.topic}}</td>
    <td>{{lesson.homework}}</td>     
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

and this is a fragment of my component.ts file

```
public lessons = [];

ngOnInit() {
this.localStorage.getItem<number>('selectedProfileId').subscribe((id) => {
     this._profileService.showLessons(id)
     .subscribe(data => this.lessons = data,
     );
   });     
 }
```

Comment: Just sort `lessons` using [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) in your component class before you bind it.

Comment: You need to show how your `lessons` property is populated and what format the `date` property is in as well as if you mean descending or ascending order.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm not sure how to use that. The lessons come from an API, the format looks like this: "date": "2018-05-27 03:00:00.0" - as for the order, i think in some components it would be ascending and in others descending - no dynamic sorting though

Comment: The answer has been updated to show how you can sort prior to subscribing. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sort `lessons` using [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) in your component class prior to subscribing/binding `lessons`. Here is how you can sort `lessons` coming in from your service prior to binding using RxJS operator `map()` in descending order. `map()` is really powerful in terms of transforming data streams prior to `subscribe()`.

```
this._profileService.showLessons(id)
    .pipe(
        map(lessons => lessons.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date).getTime() - new Date(a.date).getTime()))
    )
    .subscribe(lessons => this.lessons = lessons);
```

Depending on your TsLint settings/configuration, you may need to utilize `getTime()` to appease the compiler:

```
lessons.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date).getTime() - new Date(a.date).getTime())
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xdbua9) showing the basic functionality in action.

**Note*** - `pipe()` is using with **RxJS 5.5+**. If you are using an older version of RxJS, you can simply just import `map()` directly and using it as follows:

```
this._profileService.showLessons(id)
    .map(lessons => lessons.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date).getTime() - new Date(a.date).getTime()))
    .subscribe(lessons => this.lessons = lessons);
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunonately I am getting an error on "new Date(b)" - it said "[ts] The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type."

Comment: I added the note to the answer indicating using `getTime()` date function to please the compiler. `new Date(b.date).getTime() - new Date(a.date).getTime()`. `getTime()` returns a `number` of milliseconds so that will satisfy the warning/error from TypeScript. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
getTriLots(){
  return this.lots.sort((a,b) =>  new Date(b.date_used).getTime() - new Date(a.date_used).getTime())
}
```

Comment: It looks like you just provided some code without any explanation. Please explain yourself why this is an anwser to the question provided, elaborate on what you used and add more to it then just a code. Refer to the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for more details