# Order by start_date on ngFor Angular

Tags: angular

on select available date section i have an array date like below. [image: available date]

the code on `ngFor`

```
<div *ngFor="let date of tripdetail.trip_availabledate; let i = index;">
   <a [ngClass]="{'active': date.status}" class="btn btn-block" (click)="keyPress('currentDateSelected', i)">{{date.start_date | date:'dd MMM yyyy'}} - {{date.end_date | date:'dd MMM yyyy'}}</a>
</div>
```

the question is, how to ordering these available dates with startdates on `ngFor`?

Comment: Show `tripdetail.trip_availabledate` array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

**Sorting in controller:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.tripdetail.trip_availabledate = this.tripdetail.trip_availabledate.sort((a: any, b: any) =>
        new Date(a.start_date).getTime() - new Date(b.start_date).getTime()
    );
}
```

You can also try this using pipe.

**Sorting using Pipe**

SortBydatePipe :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sortBydate'
})
export class SortBydatePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, key?: any): any {
    return value.sort(
      (a: any, b: any) =>
        new Date(a[key]).getTime() - new Date(b[key]).getTime()
    );
  }

}
```

Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let date of tripdetail.trip_availabledate | sortBydate  : 'start_date'; let i = index;">
   <a [ngClass]="{'active': date.status}" class="btn btn-block" (click)="keyPress('currentDateSelected', i)">{{date.start_date | date:'dd MMM yyyy'}} - {{date.end_date | date:'dd MMM yyyy'}}</a>
</div>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fl3xq8?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: You are welcome. Check how to do it using pipe in modified answer

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 2+ for solve this, You have to sort collection in your controller or you can write custom pipe

Answer (score 0):

Sort trip_availabledate using Array.prototype.sort(), follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50334847/angular-5-sort-by-date).

```
public get trip_availabledate() {
    const jsonArray = [
        { start_date: new Date('2019-10-31'), end_date: new Date('2019-11-04') },
        { start_date: new Date('2019-11-10'), end_date: new Date('2019-11-14') },
        { start_date: new Date('2019-10-24'), end_date: new Date('2019-10-28') }
    ];

    // For ascending(asc) order
    const result = jsonArray.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.start_date).getTime() - new Date(b.start_date).getTime());

    // For descending(desc) order
    // const result = jsonArray.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.start_date).getTime() - new Date(a.start_date).getTime());
    return result;
}
```